# Java How to disable the JTable editable when click it

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jframe

[image: How to disable the cell editing in Jtable???]

```
public class AdminControlPanel extends javax.swing.JFrame
```

I'm using the JFrame class...so it will automatically inherit the JFrame class...
But problem now is I want to disable the cell editing in the JTable...How to do it even I'm not inherit the AbstractTableModel???

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a custom table model:

```
//instance table model
DefaultTableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel() {

   @Override
   public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {       
       return false; // or a condition at your choice with row and column
   }
};

table.setModel(tableModel);
```

Or in a quick and dirty way:

```
table.setEnabled(false);
```

This second approach is inconsistent with some L&F (it looks grayed out).

Comment: if it's inconsistent (to the extent of being unusable), it's not _simpler_ is it :-) Better remove that suggestion, as it's not an option

Comment: @jefferyleo glad you found something, just ... a) please don't shout at us, most of us aren't deaf :) b) where does a _mousePressed_ come into play? Sounds like you didn't describe your problem correctly/completely

Comment: seeing that I wasn't clear enough: to disable the component is _not_ an option (neither simple nor quick&dirty). That's a clear -1 (only zeroed by the +1 for the correct approach in the first part of your answer ;-)

Comment: @jefferyleo, a user can also use the F2 key to initiate cell editing or just start typing on the cell, so I'm not sure what your comment stating "it must be the mouse pressed event" is about. Overriding the isCellEditable(...) method of the JTable or the TableModel is how you solve the problem.